# $_get with second value not working

Tags: php

I trying  to add second $_get by using the & but for same reason it not working

```
$query = (mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` = $del"));
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            {

$link5 = "<a class='myButton' href='slideshow_on.php?filename=".$del." & filename2 =".$del2."'>slideshow 1 on </a><br />";

<td><?php   print($link5); ?></td><?php
```

this is that i get in the url bar

```
slideshow_on.php?filename=2%20&%20filename2%20=1
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put spaces in query string.

```
$link5 = "<a class='myButton' href='slideshow_on.php?filename=".$del."&filename2=".$del2."'>slideshow 1 on </a><br />";
```

Comment: thanks you i did not know that spaces would affect it